# Select All Button for Two Different Dynamically Generated Lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, checkbox

I have two unordered lists (one sorted by frequency, another alphabetically) that are generated via xQuery. The frequency sorted list is displayed by default, while the alphabetic list is hidden via Javascript. The user then has the option to click a link to display the alphabetic list, then the frequency list is hidden. The user can toggle back and forth between the lists. Both lists are displayed in a Colorbox pop-up.

I need to add checkboxes to each list and include a button that toggles between 'Select All' / 'Clear All' for each list. My problem is that when I view the frequency sorted list, click 'Select All', then click the link to view the alphabetic list, all the values are still selected and the toggle button text changes back to 'Select All'. When I click the 'Select All' button now, the text toggles back to 'Clear All', but does not uncheck the checkboxes.

Is there a way to have the checkboxes "reset" when the user toggles between the two lists? So that when they click on the alphabetic list, the checkboxes are all unchecked and the button says 'Select All'?

Here's the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.select-all:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('Clear All');
      event.preventDefault();
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('Select All');
      event.preventDefault();        
    })
  })

    <li>
    <input type="checkbox">{$display-value}</input>
    </li>

    <input type="button" value="Select all" class="select-all"></input>,
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

How come you can't treat your two list displays like the `toggle` function you're already using? When any list is displayed, the first step would be to select all child nodes that are checkboxes and remove the checked attribute.

Or, write a function that takes a parent element and traverses beneath it for child checkboxes and unchecks them. Call this function first when you pull up your first list, or switch between the two.

Is there some part of your question I'm not understanding? This seems trivial, especially since you've got code in your example that basically does what you're asking :)

Comment: Sorry I'm new to working with jQuery and this is code that I've inherited. The lists are already set up, I just need to add the checkboxes and get the 'Select All' button text to stay as 'Clear All' when a user opens the alphabetically sorted list.